# `break` and `continue` in `forEach` in Kotlin

Tags: loops, foreach, lambda, kotlin

Kotlin has very nice iterating functions, like `forEach` or `repeat`, but I am not able to make the `break` and `continue` operators work with them (both local and non-local):

```
repeat(5) {
    break
}

(1..5).forEach {
    continue@forEach
}
```

The goal is to mimic usual loops with the functional syntax as close as it might be. It was definitely possible in some older versions of Kotlin, but I struggle to reproduce the syntax.

The problem might be a bug with labels (M12), but I think that the first example should work anyway.

It seems to me that I've read somewhere about a special trick/annotation, but I could not find any reference on the subject. Might look like the following:

```
public inline fun repeat(times: Int, @loop body: (Int) -> Unit) {
    for (index in 0..times - 1) {
        body(index)
    }
}
```

Comment: In current Kotlin you can indeed mimic this (while waiting for the `continue@label` and `break@label` features), see related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642868/how-do-i-do-a-break-or-continue-when-in-a-functional-loop-within-kotlin

Comment: This question could use clarification about whether you are asking only about the existance of `break` and `continue` for functional loops, or if you are seeking alternative answers that do exactly the same thing.  The former appears to be the case, because you rejected the latter.

Comment: it seems they are added that in kotlin 1.3

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan wow! Do you have a link?

Comment: @voddan, no, I just tried it works

Answer (score 225, accepted):

**Edit**:
According to Kotlin's [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html), it is possible to simulate `continue` using annotations.

```
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach lit@ {
        if (it == 3) return@lit // local return to the caller of the lambda, i.e. the forEach loop
        print(it)
    }
    print(" done with explicit label")
}
```

If you want to simulate a `break`, just add a `run` block

```
fun foo() {
    run lit@ {
        listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
            if (it == 3) return@lit // local return to the caller of the lambda, i.e. the forEach loop
            print(it)
        }
        print(" done with explicit label")
    }
}
```

---

**Original Answer**:
Since you supply a `(Int) -> Unit`, you can't break from it, since the compiler do not know that it is used in a loop.

You have few options:

**Use a regular for loop:**

```
for (index in 0 until times) {
    // your code here
}
```

**If the loop is the last code in the method**
you can use `return` to get out of the method (or `return value` if it is not `unit` method).

**Use a method**
Create a custom repeat method method that returns `Boolean` for continuing.

```
public inline fun repeatUntil(times: Int, body: (Int) -> Boolean) {
    for (index in 0 until times) {
        if (!body(index)) break
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, my question was about making the specific syntax work, not about iterating. Don't you remember that it was possible at some Kotlin milestone?

Comment: I don't remember. But maybe it is because I don't use break & continue a lot. See [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1436), it says "Estimation - No estimation".

Comment: `break` and `continue` only work in loops. `forEach`, `repeat` and all the other methods are just that: methods and not loops. Yoav presented some alternatives but `break` and `continue` are just not ment to work for methods.

Comment: @YoavSternberg Brilliant! This peace of old docs is what I was looking for! So the feature is not implemented yet, left for future versions. If you care to create a separate answer, I'll mark it

Comment: In current Kotlin you can indeed mimic this (while waiting for the `continue@label` and `break@label` features), see related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642868/how-do-i-do-a-break-or-continue-when-in-a-functional-loop-within-kotlin

Comment: Instead of `for (index in 0..times - 1)` you can write: `for (index in 0 until times)`.

Comment: These are labels, not annotations.

Comment: `return@lit` returning to `run lit@` does not work if `forEach` is used on array created using `"abcd".chars()` i.e something like `"abcd".chars().forEach {...return@lit...}`

Comment: Oh yeah, this is SOOOO much simpler and more intuitive than java.  I'm so glad we switched.

Answer (score 333):

This will print 1 to 5. The `return@forEach` acts like the keyword `continue` in Java, which means in this case, it still executes every loop but skips to the next iteration if the value is greater than 5.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val nums = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    nums.forEach {
       if (it > 5) return@forEach
       println(it)
    }
}
```

This will print 1 to 10 but skips 5.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val nums = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    nums.forEach {
       if (it == 5) return@forEach
       println(it)
    }
}
```

This will print 1 to 4, and break when reaching 5.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val nums = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    
    run breaking@ {
        nums.forEach {
           if (it == 5) return@breaking
           println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to code snippet from ashuges](https://pl.kotl.in/Yoa9cxHZr).

Comment: Great, but this still doesn't address the problem of not being able to end the forEach prematurely when some condition is met. It still keeps on executing the loop.

Comment: @TheFox yes, it executes every loop and anything after the return is skipped when condition is met. Each operation in the forEach is a lambda function, currently there is no exact break operation for the forEach operation. The break is available in for loops, see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Comment: Here's a runnable Kotlin Playground snippet with both a `continue` and `break` example: https://pl.kotl.in/_LAvET-wX

Comment: They reinvented goto"

Answer (score 83):

A break can be achieved using:

```
//Will produce "12 done with nested loop"
//Using "run" and a tag will prevent the loop from running again.
//Using return@forEach if I>=3 may look simpler, but it will keep running the loop and checking if i>=3 for values >=3 which is a waste of time.
fun foo() {
    run loop@{
        listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
            if (it == 3) return@loop // non-local return from the lambda passed to run
            print(it)
        }
    }
    print(" done with nested loop")
}
```

And a continue can be achieved with:

```
//Will produce: "1245 done with implicit label"
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
        if (it == 3) return@forEach // local return to the caller of the lambda, i.e. the forEach loop
        print(it)
    }
    print(" done with implicit label")
}
```

As anyone here recommends... read the docs :P
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels

**EDIT:**
While the main question asks about forEach, it's important to consider the the good old "for". Using Kotlin doesn't mean we need to use forEach all the time. Using the good old "for" is perfectly ok, and sometimes even more expressive and concise than forEach:

```
fun foo() {
    for(x in listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5){
        if (x == 3) break //or continue
        print(x)
    }
    print("done with the good old for")
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Works very well. Though it seems like without using `@loop` gives the same desired result as well.

Comment: In fact, you can omit the explicit tag "@loop" and use the implicit one "@run". The key aspect here is the local return to the caller of the lambda. Note you need to wrap the loop inside some scope so you can local return on it  later on.

Comment: This really answers the question, however i think this probably isn't the right path to take for functional programming. What we need is, from Lodash, `transform` where you can break under certain condition, ex. `reduceReturnIf(acc, value, returnIf: func)`

Answer (score 43):

As the [Kotlin documentation says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html), using `return` is the way to go. Good thing about `Kotlin` is that if you have nested functions, you can use labels to explicitly write where your `return` is from:

###### Function Scope Return

```
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach {
        /** Non-local return directly to the caller of foo(). */
        if (it == 3) return
        print(it)
    }

    println("this point is unreachable")
}
```

###### Local Return

It doesn't stop going through `forEach` loop (it's like a `continue` in `for` loop).

```
fun foo() {
    listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach lit@{
        /** Local return to the caller of the lambda, i.e. the forEach loop. */
        if (it == 3) return@lit
        print(it)
    }

    print(" done with explicit label")
}
```

Check out the documentation, it's really good :)

Comment: Warning: return@lit  does not stop `forEach`

Comment: That is correct. It's intended. The first solution it does, but if you have instructions inside a loop you can choose where do you want to return to / jump to. In the second case, if we just use return it will stop ;-)

Comment: Calling Return@lit likes Continue

Answer (score 31):

You can use [return from lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) which mimics a `continue` or `break` depending on your usage.

This is covered in the related question:  [How do I do a "break" or "continue" when in a functional loop within Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642868/how-do-i-do-a-break-or-continue-when-in-a-functional-loop-within-kotlin)

Answer (score 19):

`continue` type behaviour in `forEach`

```
list.forEach { item -> // here forEach give you data item and you can use it 
    if () {
        // your code
        return@forEach // Same as continue
    }

    // your code
}
```

for `break` type behaviour you have to use `for in until` or `for in` as per the list is `Nullable` or `Non-Nullable`

1. For **Nullable** list:

   ```
   for (index in 0 until list.size) {
       val item = list[index] // you can use data item now
       if () {
           // your code
           break
       }

       // your code
   }
   ```
2. For **Non-Nullable** list:

   ```
   for (item in list) { // data item will available right away
       if () {
           // your code
           break
       }

       // your code
   }
   ```

Answer (score 8):

I have the perfect solution for this (:

```
list.apply{ forEach{ item ->
    if (willContinue(item)) return@forEach
    if (willBreak(item)) return@apply
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Break statement for nested loops forEach():

```
listOf("a", "b", "c").forEach find@{ i ->
    listOf("b", "d").forEach { j ->
        if (i == j) return@find
        println("i = $i, j = $j")
    }
}
```

Result:

```
i = a, j = b
i = a, j = d
i = c, j = b
i = c, j = d
```

Continue statement with anonymous function:

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).forEach(fun(value: Int) {
    if (value == 3) return
    print("$value ")
})
```

Result:

```
1 2 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe change `forEach` to this:

```
for (it in myList) {
    if (condition) {
        doSomething()
    } else {
        break // or continue
    }
}
```

It works for `HashMap`'s:

```
 for (it in myMap) {
     val k = it.key
     val v = it.value

     if (condition) {
         doSomething()
     } else {
         break // or continue
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think it is the right alternative for using break or continue

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only truly general solution.  The other answers only work in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems much better use For loop like this: `for (item in list){ break }`

Answer (score 0):

```
fun part2(ops: List<Int>): Int = ops.asSequence()
    .scan(0) { acc, v -> acc + v }
    .indexOf(-1)
```

If you can afford to turn a collection into a `sequence`, normally the cost is trivial, then you should be able to take advantage of the deferred feature.

> You might already notice `asSequence` in the above. It's here for saving us going over the entire list. Right after we have a match via `indexOf`, it'll stop. Bingo! Saving us write a `while` here.

as in Part 2 of [medium article](https://medium.com/@windmaomao/kotlin-day-1-up-and-down-38885a5fc2b1).

Answer (score 0):

If the condition depends on the outcome of a previous element in the list, you can use `sequence` and `takeWhile` to execute depth-first lazily.

```kotlin
sequenceOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map { i ->
    println("i = ${i}")
    i < 3
}.takeWhile { success ->
    println("success = ${success}")
    success
}.toList()
```

will print

```
i = 1
success = true
i = 2
success = true
i = 3
success = false
```

You need the terminal `toList()` in the end to execute the sequence.

More details: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html#sequence