# How do I do a "break" or "continue" when in a functional loop within Kotlin?

Tags: loops, functional-programming, break, kotlin, continue

In Kotlin, I cannot do a `break` or `continue` within a function loop and my lambda -- like I can from a normal `for` loop.  For example, this does not work:

```kotlin
(1..5).forEach {
    continue@forEach  // not allowed, nor break@forEach
}
```

There are [old documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/Kotlin/Returns+and+jumps#Returnsandjumps-Breakandcontinueincustomcontrolstructures) that mentions this being available but it appears it was never implemented.  What is the best way to get the same behavior when I want to `continue` or `break` from within the lambda?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that the idiomatic answers to commonly asked Kotlin topics are present in SO.  Also to clarify some really old answers written for alphas of Kotlin that are not accurate for current-day Kotlin.*

Comment: Note: it is good to mention IDE(Android studio maybe Intellij too) not show a warning when use return@forEach in last line of forEach function lambda.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1436: "October 2022
Compiler implementation is ready in all backends, IDE support and documentation with KEEP is in progress"

Comment: "soon" ... no release indicated yet, probably in 1.8.x chain

Answer (score 137, accepted):

There are other options other than what you are asking for that provide similar functionality.  For example:

You can avoid processing some values using [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html):  (*like a `continue`*)

```
dataSet.filter { it % 2 == 0 }.forEach {
    // do work on even numbers
}
```

You can stop a functional loop by using [`takeWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-while.html): (*like a `break`*)

```
dataSet.takeWhile { it < 10 }.forEach {
    // do work on numbers as long as they are < 10, otherwise stop
}
```

A more complex, although nonsensical example where you want to do some processing, skip some resulting values, and then stop at a set of different conditions, would be:

```
dataSet.asSequence()
       .takeWhile { it >=  0 }    // a -1 signals end of the dataset (break)
       .map { it + 1 }            // increment each number
       .filterNot { it % 5 == 0 } // skip (continue) numbers divisible by 5
       .map { it - 1 }            // decrement each number by 1
       .filter { it < 100 }       // skip (continue) if number is >= 100
       .drop(5)                   // ignore the first 5 numbers
       .take(10)                  // use the next 10 numbers and end
       .forEach {
           // do work on the final list
       }
```

A combination of these functions tends to eliminate the need for `continue` or `break`.  And there are endless different options here and more than can be documented.  To get an idea of what can be done, it is best if you learn all of the functions available in the Kotlin standard library for [collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/index.html#kotlin.collections.Collection), lazy [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html), and [iterable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/index.html#kotlin.collections.Iterable).

Sometimes there are cases where you have mutating state that still needs to `break` or `continue` and is hard to do in a functional model.  You can make it work using more complex functions like `fold` and `reduce` combined with the `filter` and `takeWhile` functions but sometimes that is harder to grok.  Therefore if you really want that exact behavior you can use [return from lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) which mimics a `continue` or `break` depending on your usage.

Here is a an example mimicking `continue`:

```
(1..5).forEach  {
    if (it == 3) return@forEach  // mimic continue@forEach
    // ... do something more
}
```

And you can go more complicated and use labels when you having nesting or confusing situations:

```
(1..3).forEach outer@ { x ->
    (1..3).forEach inner@ { y ->
        if (x == 2 && y == 2) return@outer // mimic continue@outer
        if (x == 1 && y == 1) return@inner // mimic continue@inner
        // ... do something more
    }
}
```

If you want to do a `break` you need something outside the loop that you can return from, here we will use the `run()` function to help us:

```
run breaker@ {
    (1..20).forEach { x ->
        if (x == 5) return@breaker  // mimic break@forEach
        // ... do something more
    }
}
```

Instead of `run()` it could be `let()` or `apply()` or anything naturally you have surrounding the `forEach` that is a place you want to break from.  But you will also skip the code within the same block following the `forEach` so be careful.

These are inlined functions so really they do not really add overhead.

Read the Kotlin reference docs for [Returns and Jumps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html) for all the special cases including for anonymous functions.

---

**Here is a unit test** proving this all works:

```
@Test fun testSo32540947() {
    val results = arrayListOf<Pair<Int,Int>>()
    (1..3).forEach outer@ { x ->
        (1..3).forEach inner@ { y ->
            if (x == 2 && y == 2) return@outer // continue @outer
            if (x == 1 && y == 1) return@inner // continue @inner
            results.add(Pair(x,y))
        }
    }

    assertEquals(listOf(Pair(1,2), Pair(1,3), Pair(2,1), Pair(3,1), Pair(3,2), Pair(3,3)), results)

    val results2 = arrayListOf<Int>()
    run breaker@ {
        (1..20).forEach { x ->
            if (x == 5) return@breaker
            results2.add(x)
        }
    }

    assertEquals(listOf(1,2,3,4), results2)
}
```

Comment: Using breaks and returns with labels like this is a code smell (IMHO). See @user8320224's answer below for a much more elegant and idiomatic functional solution.

Comment: @Mark I adjusted the answer to be a combination of the functional models for this, and the literal answer.

Comment: @store88 extended the answer to provide more options.

Comment: unfortunately filter gives me a new list so I cant use it if I need to mutate something and @breaker needs something to label outside of it so its situational

Comment: forEachIndexed?

Answer (score 2):

[takeWhile](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-while.html) stdlib function may be used instead of break.

For example,

```
val array = arrayOf(2, 8, 4, 5, 13, 12, 16)
array.takeWhile { it % 2 == 0 }.forEach { println(it) } // break on odd
array.takeWhile { it % 3 != 0 }.forEach { println(it) } // break on 3 * n
```

Comment: A usage example would improve your answer.

Comment: Beware that this would copy all satisfying elements into newly allocated intermediate collection.

Comment: When dealing with a sequence instead of (or created from) an array, the aforementioned concern about intermediate collections is irrelevant (since sequences are lazy and don't build intermediate collections).  IMHO, this is a better answer than the accepted one, you just need to use it on a sequence.

Comment: Sequences are not always faster, depends on list size and the actions taken. This has been proven repeatedly.

Comment: @JaysonMinard if your comment was addressed to me (seems like it is), note that i didn't say a sequence would be faster--just that using a sequence would nullify the previously stated concern about intermediate collections.

Comment: it was just a generic thought to make sure that wasn't inferred as well.