# How to return outside of forEach in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to return to the line `aa@ logError("Done")` outside `forEach`, but `return@aa` doesn't work,  and `break@label` doesn't work too.

And more, if you use `return`, it will be return outside the fun `lookForAlice` !

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
val people = listOf(Person("Paul", 30), Person("Alice", 29), Person("Bob", 31))


fun lookForAlice(people: List<Person>) {
    people.forEach label@{
        logError("Each: "+it.name)
        if (it.name == "Alice") {
            logError("Find")                                 
            return@aa  //It's fault
        }
    }
    aa@ logError("Done")
}

lookForAlice(people)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the traditional way "for-each" loop.

i.e. change

```
people.forEach label@{
```

to

```
for (it in people) {
```

and change `return` to `break`.

---

**NOTE**: Read these articles about `return` in `.forEach()`

[`break` and `continue` in `forEach` in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540947/break-and-continue-in-foreach-in-kotlin)

[How do I do a "break" or "continue" when in a functional loop within Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642868/how-do-i-do-a-break-or-continue-when-in-a-functional-loop-within-kotlin) (The question may be a duplicate of this link)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `find` instead. It'll return `Person?`. So you can just check if it's null, or not. If not, you found `Alice`.

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
val people = listOf(Person("Paul", 30), Person("Alice", 29), Person("Bob", 31))
val alice: Person? = findAlice(people)


fun findAlice(people: List<Person>): Person? {
    return people.find { it.name == "Alice" }
}
```