# I can't exist from map's iteration

Tags: android, kotlin

I iterate map and want to exit when executed this line:

```
mostOccurRecognizedCheck = filterList.get(0)
```

here snippet:

```
val maxIndexesMap: Map<Int, Int> =
            howOftenCheckIndexMap.filter { it.value == findMaxCount }
    maxIndexesMap.forEach lit@{ (indexMaxCount, value) ->
                val filterList: List<Check> =
                    recognizedCheckList.filterIndexed { index, check -> index == indexMaxCount && check.amount != null }
                if (filterList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Debug.d(
                        TAG,
                        "getMostOccurRecognizedCheck: get_first_item from RESULT_FILTER_LIST(${filterList.size}) = $filterList"
                    )
                    mostOccurRecognizedCheck = filterList.get(0)
                    return@lit 
                } else {
                    Debug.w(
                        TAG,
                        "getMostOccurRecognizedCheck: filterList_is_empty -> get_item_from_index = $indexMaxCount in recognizedCheckList"
                    )
                    mostOccurRecognizedCheck = recognizedCheckList.get(indexMaxCount)
                }
            }
```

and here log:

```
getMostOccurRecognizedCheck: findMaxCount = 1 -> maxIndexesMap = {1=1, 0=1, 3=1, 2=1}
getMostOccurRecognizedCheck: get_first_item from RESULT_FILTER_LIST(1) = [
Check(fuel = GPL, fuelPrice = 9.87, volume = 10.13, amount = 100.0, tva = 7.41, date = Mon Jan 06 15:07:17 GMT+02:00 2020, name=null, address=null, idno=null, codFiscal=null, id=0, transactionID=null
getMostOccurRecognizedCheck: get_first_item from RESULT_FILTER_LIST(1) = [
Check(fuel = null, fuelPrice = null, volume = null, amount = 100.0, tva = null, date = null, name=null, address=null, idno=null, codFiscal=null, id=0, transactionID=null, ]
getMostOccurRecognizedCheck: get_first_item from RESULT_FILTER_LIST(1) = [
Check(fuel = GPL, fuelPrice = 9.87, volume = 10.13, amount = 100.0, tva = null, date = Wed Jan 08 15:07:17 GMT+02:00 2020, name=null, address=null, idno=null, codFiscal=null, id=0, transactionID=null, ]
getMostOccurRecognizedCheck: get_first_item from RESULT_FILTER_LIST(1) = [
Check(fuel = GPL, fuelPrice = 9.87, volume = 10.13, amount = 100.0, tva = null, date = Mon Jan 06 15:07:17 GMT+02:00 2020, name=null, address=null, idno=null, codFiscal=null, id=0, transactionID=null, ]
```

As you can see the

```
get_first_item
```

print 4 times.
Why?

I use this to exit

```
return@lit
```

but it not help

Comment: Becase the return@* inside foreach works like a `continue` in java. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47639682/2235972). Solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540947/break-and-continue-in-foreach-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` will run for each element of the map, there's no stopping that. Your `return` statement will simply return from that single execution of the lambda.

If you want to find some element (and return that) then `.find` is a better fit:

```
  maxIndexesMap.find { (indexMaxCount, value) ->
                val filterList: List<Check> =
                    recognizedCheckList.filterIndexed { index, check -> index == indexMaxCount && check.amount != null }
                !filterList.empty() 
  }?.let { (indexMaxCount, value) ->
    // Log
  }
```

(you need the `?.let` in case there are no elements for which filterList is not empty).

Note that this won't log anything for the 'other' cases.